# How to get query params in root component?

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 2, is it possible to get the query params in the root component in an "angular way"?

I have a simple [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ktfKaUPgCyqmrpGTvCiL?p=preview) with a root component and two routes/states.
I try to get the parameters with :

```
export class App implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
  }
}
```

If I open the example with a query parameter : [plnkr](https://run.plnkr.co/RjmsavN6pI07yXyy/#/?token=12345678) the object in the console log is empty.
But when I click the "One" or "Two" links, it can get the query parameters.

I suppose the root can't see the query parameters because it's not an activated route.
Would the solution be to create a fake root route? Or is there another way to read the url (not talking about native JS).

My use case : Regardless of the route I'm on, I need to be able to check if there is a "token" in the url, read from it and then remove it.

Comment: At the moment when you open the example you are simply visiting the app, and aren't specifying any query parameters.

Comment: Yes, that's why I specified a second link with extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my change:

https://plnkr.co/edit/b45VUvfVqUl5u2EuzNI9?p=preview

```
{
path: '**',
component: App
}
```

I've added a default route - which should be added to the router. This basically says for any other route passed in then go here.

```
<a routerLink="**" [queryParams]="{token:12345678}">Home</a>
```

In the links i added a home link, similar to your other links. When you navigate to one or two, then back to home you will see the token passed in the object.
This is because the token was specified in the link.

This only really works if the link will have the token, either hard coded or dynamically generated by another component.

This might help:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Comment: By adding routes for every case, that means each component has to have its own param fetching logic.

That's why I needed something I could use in the root component's OnInit.